# Filter by hostname is not working in my WireShark

Tags: rest, ssl, tcp, wireshark, insomnia

I am using RESTFul client `Insomnia` to test my `GET` request.

I get 500 `internal server error` as shown below

```
  * Preparing request to https://sample.azure-api.net/masterData/carTypes
  * Using libcurl/7.57.0-DEV OpenSSL/1.0.2o zlib/1.2.11 libssh2/1.7.0_DEV
  * Current time is 2019-08-30T05:03:09.029Z
  * Disable timeout
  * Enable automatic URL encoding
  * Enable SSL validation
  * Enable cookie sending with jar of 0 cookies
  * Found bundle for host sample.azure-api.net: 0x205d69260b0 [can pipeline]
  * Re-using existing connection! (#7) with host sample.azure-api.net
  * Connected to sample.azure-api.net (XX.XXX.XXX.XX) port 443 (#7)

  > GET /masterData/carTypes HTTP/1.1
  > Host: sample.azure-api.net
  > User-Agent: insomnia/6.6.2
  > Accept: */*

  < HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
  < Content-Length: 111
  < Content-Type: application/json
  < Date: Fri, 30 Aug 2019 05:03:09 GMT
```

To troubleshoot, I opened `wireshark`, selected `Ethernet2` interface and started to capture the traffic. also added a filter as follow

> http.host == "sample.azure-api.net"

But I do not see any traffic filtered when I apply the above filter.

But when I try to filter like `IP Destination`, I get to see the traffic.

> ip.dst == XX.XXX.XXX.XX  &&   tcp.port == 443

Why filter by **hostname** is not working?

**What I am trying to solve? Root Issue**

When I try same request from c# code using rest client, I get below error

> {"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."}

So basically I am trying to find where exactly is request is failing!

Comment: Have you checked DNS if there is only one IP assigned to your DNS name?

Comment: how do I check it? It's microsoft azure hostnames

Comment: You know the `nslookup` command-line command?

Comment: I dont have DNS assigned in dev environments.  as I said earlier it's azure built in hostnames